# explain apache status

Tags: apache-2.2

My Apache Status Page shows several stats and shortcuts.
Some are easy to understand other aren't explained...

who could explain me the following data words from my apache status page in detail?
it looks similar to this one: >http://www.apache.org/server-status

`Parent Server Generation: 33` Resets?

`Total accesses: 2458466` Requests?

`CPU Usage: u33.6 s9.83 cu45.75 cs0 - .00579% CPU load` u? s? cu? cs?

`1.6 requests/sec - 3473 B/second - 2177 B/request` requests/sec a day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Parent Server Generation: 33 Resets?

[Number of times you have instructed apache to re-read its configuration file and gracefully restart all child processes.](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=650636)

> Total accesses: 2458466 Requests?

Number of requests to server.

> CPU Usage: u33.6 s9.83 cu45.75 cs0 - .00579% CPU load u? s? cu? cs?

u=user, s=system... cu and cs are the cumulative values of u and s

> 1.6 requests/sec - 3473 B/second - 2177 B/request requests/sec a day?

uptime

Comment: `cu` and `cs` are not cumulative values, but childrens' user and system usage time.