# Understanding the Apache server-status page

Tags: apache-2.4, apache-2.2

The following is a sample server status page taken from [Apache website](https://www.apache.org/server-status?refresh=30):

```
Current Time: Thursday, 01-May-2014 07:38:59 UTC
Restart Time: Friday, 11-Apr-2014 18:30:33 UTC
Parent Server Config. Generation: 27
Parent Server MPM Generation: 26
Server uptime: 19 days 13 hours 8 minutes 26 seconds
Server load: 4.90 5.10 5.39
Total accesses: 200912024 - Total Traffic: 24965.1 GB
CPU Usage: u5133.55 s2390.16 cu0 cs0 - .445% CPU load
119 requests/sec - 15.1 MB/second - 130.3 kB/request
351 requests currently being processed, 417 idle workers
```

I need to understand what the values in `Server load` stand for as the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html) did not say anything about it.

Also, from [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/225915/107359), I understand that the `u`, `s` and `c` stand for `user`, `system` and `cumulative` figures respectively. What do the actual numbers `5133.55` and `0` represent?

Comment: @Raptor, not a duplicate because I have already read and  _linked_ to that page in the last paragraph of my question and I am asking the meaning of those numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server load entries are the [CPU load values](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages) for the server.

I believe the numbers for user and system indicate the total cpu time, in seconds, that httpd has been using.  This would only count time the threads are actually in the running state, not sleeping.  So yours has spent 85.55 minutes in userland, and 39.83 minutes running system calls.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful article about CPU load. However, if `5133.55` represents the amount of time the CPU spent running as user, then what is `0`? And why is `CPU load` given as `0.445%` when the one-minute Server load (CPU load value) is 4.9 (or 490%)?

Comment: A good question.  The percentage value is the amount of CPU time used over the existence of the process.  eg:  Your server has been up for 19d13h8m26s=(((19*24)+13)*60+8)*60+26=1688906 seconds.  Apache used the CPU for 5133.55user+2390.16sys=7523.71 seconds.  So the fraction is 7523.71used/1688906possible=.00445-.445% of possible CPU time taken by Apache.